# Extraer resultado de una funcion

Tags: json, nodejs, array

Buenas gente, tengo esta funcion que uso para analizar unos textos, el tema es que necesito incluir los datos en un array, hago esto dentro de la funcion usando data, que lo trae esta funcion, pero luego la variable 'sentiments' queda vacia, y no puedo utilizarla fuera de la funcion, cual seria la forma de lograr que sentiments, se le haga el push y llegue con los resultados a el callback?

```js
        for(var i=0; i<texts.length; i++){
          ibmWatson.analize(texts[i], function (error, data)
           {
              sentiments.push(data.result);
           });
        }

         callback(null, sentiments);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas asegurarte de que la función se ha ejecutado todas las veces que hace falta. Realmente tu bucle no la ejecuta, simplemente declara su ejecución N veces donde N es `texts.length`:

```
let analyzedCount = 0; //numero de ejecuciones de la función addToSentiments

for(var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++){
  ibmWatson.analize(texts[i], function addToSentiments (error, data) {
    sentiments.push(data.result);
    analyzedCount++;
    if (analyzedCount === texts.length) {
      callback(null, sentiments); //si se ha ejecutado todas las veces, llamamos
    } 
  });
}
```

Ejemplo simplificado de ejecución:

```js
let datos=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
let sentiments=[];

let analyzedCount = 0;

function analizar(dato,funcionCallback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Analizando ${dato}`);
      funcionCallback(null,dato*10);
    });
}

function callback(algo) {
  console.log(algo);
}    
for(var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){
  analizar(datos[i], function (error, data) {
    sentiments.push(data);
  analyzedCount++;
    if (analyzedCount === datos.length) {
      callback(sentiments); //si se ha ejecutado todas las veces, llamamos
    } 
  });
}

console.log('bucle terminado');
```

Comment: Grandee! Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Si esto te resuelve la duda... ¿podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada?

Comment: Claro, estaba esperando que stack me dejara hacerlo, saludos!